# Query builder - adding methods depending on if statement

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with query builder notation. I would like to add additional methods depending on if statement. I'm writhing like below but it is not working

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('k')
 ->where('k.autor LIKE :autor OR k.tytul LIKE :tytul ');
if($tag!==''){
                  $repository->createQueryBuilder('k')->andWhere('k.cena=:jezyk');
                  $repository->createQueryBuilder('k') ->setParameter('jezyk',$tag);        
              }

$repository->createQueryBuilder('k')->setParameter('autor', '%' . $s . '%');
$repository->createQueryBuilder('k')->setParameter('tytul', '%' . $s . '%');

query=$repository->createQueryBuilder('k')->getQuery();
$searched_books = $query->getResult();
```

I suppose that I made mistakeswith objects. Can somebody h.lp me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the `createQueryBuilder` method will create a new query builder at each call. You should try something like that:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('k');
$qb->where('k.autor LIKE :autor OR k.tytul LIKE :tytul');

if ($tag !== '') {
    $qb->andWhere('k.cena = :jezyk');
    $qb->setParameter('jezyk', $tag);        
}

$qb->setParameter('autor', '%' . $s . '%');
$qb->setParameter('tytul', '%' . $s . '%');

$searched_books = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```